# Change language mode for multiple files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

apologies if this is a silly question, but does anyone know if it's possible to change the language mode for a bunch of files at once? I'm working on a project with hundreds of Jinja templates, but as all the files are `.html` I have to manually switch the language mode for each one to get the correct syntax highlighting.

Ideally I'd just like to select them all in the file sidebar and update the language settings for each file, but I imagine pretty much any solution would be quicker than the current method!

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSC does not store the languageId of the file, it uses the file extension that can be overruled by a setting.

Add this to your project settings in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's saved a lot of time :) Out of interest - you say it doesn't store the languageId for a file, but if I go in and manually override the language for a single file, that data must be stored *somewhere* - right? (and if so, do you know where?)

Comment: @OmidAntiLong It is stored in the current editor and when you close that editor that setting is gone

Comment: PS> If this is a blank `settings.json`, you'll need to enclose that entire code snippet in curly braces `{ } `. Thx @rioV8!

Comment: Passing a filepath with a `/` doesn't work

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy then you have to file a feature request at the VSC repo